# Prove $|tr(PAP') - tr(PBP')| \leq ||A-B||_{\infty} ||P'||_1^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

How can I show the following identity?

$|\text{tr}(PAP') - \text{tr}(PBP')| \leq ||A-B||_{\infty} ||P'||_1^2$

Comment: What is $P$ (and what happened to him)?

Comment: @lcv: $P$ is a matrix that I am interested in estimating. I am not sure what you are trying to mean by "what happened to him"?

Comment: What is the relationship between $P$ and $P'$?

Comment: $P'$ is the transpose of $P$.

Answer (score 2):

You have 
$$
|\text{tr}(PAP') - \text{tr}(PBP')|=|\text{tr}(PAP'-PBP')|=|\text{tr}(P(A-B)P')|=|\text{tr}((A-B)P'P)|.
$$
Now you apply the well-known Hölder inequality 
$$
|\text{tr}(XY)|\leq \|X\|_\infty\,\|Y\|_1. 
$$

If you don't see it, here are more details. From the above, you get 
$$
|\text{tr}(PAP') - \text{tr}(PBP')|\leq\|A-B\|_\infty\,\|P'P\|_1. 
$$
With $\{\mu_j\}$ the singular values of $P$, you have $$\|P'P\|_1=\sum_j\mu_j^2\leq\left(\sum_j\mu_j\right)^2=\|P\|_1^2.$$

Comment: Is there a type in the Holder's inequality? What happened to Y? I can't see how this can be used to prove the upper bound

Comment: Yes, the second one was a $Y$.